# How to make hidden rows not editable/copiable in VBA?

Tags: vba, edit, hidden, rows, autofilter

The macro hides rows. After the rows are hidden, users can copy, edit and delete blocks of cells/rows. When users select the range that contains hidden cells, hidden cells, unfortunately, got selected also, so all actions are performed on hidden cells too.

Is it possible to hide rows in a such way, so they do not participate in actions performed on visible part of worksheet (behave as hidden rows after autofilter)?

To hide rows I use this code:

```
 Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of.  You will probably need to look at protecting the worksheet and locking cells that you don't want modified/copied.

Comment: Thanks, Reafidy. I think it should be possible without protecting worksheet, Autofilter does it in some way and worksheet do not appear to be protected. I hope there is some way to change hidden rows' properties so they stop participating in actions done on visual part of worksheet.

Comment: Maybe, but it is likely to be hackish.  Do you have a reason why you want to avoid sheet protection?  What determines which rows you hide and can you use auto-filter instead of hiding rows?

Comment: Basically, I want to replicate autofilter functionality. The built in autofilter allows to filter only by two values within custom filters. I want to make extension where users can execute, create, edit and store complex dynamic filters. Regarding the sheet protection - I have to try it out but on my first glance it will not help to make hidden rows "uncopyable".

Comment: I think they will be "uncopyable", as how will you copy the rows if you cannot select them?